# Mock files, but generate real files

Tags: java, mockito

I use the SpringBoot mail component to generate eml files. When I use mockito to simulate, Why would a real file be generated?

This is my demo

```
@Resource
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

public File createEml(String filename) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    File file = new File(filename);
    try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        mimeMessage.writeTo(fos);
    }
    return file;
}
```

}

test

```
@InjectMocks
private EmailManager emailManager = new EmailManager();

@Mock
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;


@BeforeEach
private void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
}

@Test
void testCreateEml() throws MessagingException, IOException {
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = Mockito.mock(MimeMessage.class);
    Mockito.doNothing().when(mimeMessage).writeTo(Mockito.any(FileOutputStream.class));
    Mockito.when(javaMailSender.createMimeMessage()).thenReturn(mimeMessage);
    emailManager.createEml("test.eml");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don’t create a mock of `EmailManager`
Usually `@InjectMocks` annotation is use on the class that you’re about to test (`EmailManager` in this case)
This is a real code that you don’t want to mock (there is no point to write a test that tests a mock) - you always want to test the real code and mocks is just an auxiliary tool to “mimic” the behavior of dependencies

So in the `EmailManager` the method `createEml` is real - and file creation is just what it does - you’ve posted the source code of it. This code gets executed during the test. That’s it.

So if you want to create a test that doesn’t create any real file you should refactor the file creation part in a way that it will support file creation of “virtual” files in memory. After all not any arbitrarily-written pieces of code can are automatically unit-testable, you have to design the code with “unit-test ability” in mind

Comment: I don't have a deeper understanding of the concept of unit testing, thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Sure thing, you're welcome, and welcome to SO platform in general :)